# Retrieving firebase data in one go

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to retrive a collection named jobs in which each job contains 3 different fields. I then want to display each job with all 3 field on an array list. My app runs but it returns one item which says: java.lang.field@2234456

This is my code:

```
 ListView jobList;
 ArrayList<String> jobInfo = new ArrayList<String>();
 ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter;
 Task hello;
 String hi;
 FieldPath ha;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_see_jobs2);
    jobList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.jobList);
    setTitle("Hello");
    arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, jobInfo);
    jobList.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    jobList.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    hello = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collectionGroup("jobs").get().addOnCompleteListener(new 
     OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
            hi = QuerySnapshot.class.getFields().toString();
            hi.toString();
        }
    });
    jobInfo.add(QuerySnapshot.class.getDeclaredFields().toString());
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is **not** the way to get data from a Firestore document:

```
QuerySnapshot.class.getFields()
```

Instead this looks up the fields that are declared on the `QuerySnapshot` class, which is not at all what you're interested in.

If we check the Firebase documentation on [getting data from multiple documents](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_multiple_documents_from_a_collection), you'll see that we can get the data with:

```
public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
        for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
            Log.d(TAG, document.getId() + " => " + document.getData());
        }
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "Error getting documents: ", task.getException());
    }
}
```

So this:

1. Loops over the documents that you get back from the database.
2. Then gets the data from each document with `document.getData()`, which returns a `Map`.

---

If you look at the reference documentation for the [`DocumentSnapshot` class](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentSnapshot), you'll see that we can also get the value for a specific field with:

```
document.get("nameOfThefield")
```

---

You'll then want to add the field values to `jobInfo.add(...)` **inside** the `onComplete` method.